# is there a way to tell react to dynamically create div if not found

Tags: dom, reactjs, dynamic-html, virtual-dom

New to react and I'm wondering if there is any work around to get past this error:

`_registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.`

**EDIT** What I'm trying to do is:

I have a react function like:

`ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(someFunction,{data:someData}),document.getElementById('someID')`

which generates a `dom` like :

```
<span>
    <ul data-reactid='...'>blahhh</ul>
    <div data-reactid='...'>
        <div id='some-id1' data-reactid='...'>blahhh</div>
        <div id='some-id2'data-reactid='...'>blahhhh</div>
    </div>
</span>
```

Now on the very next line to the previous react call, I have other function which is trying to do stuff with the above  created div:

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(someOtherReactFunction, { somePram: 'ImParam'}), document.getElementById('some-id1'));
```

This gives me:

`_registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.`

But I can see it's present in the DOM

So how do I access this virtual dom `div`? and load some contents in it?

P.S: I know a way with `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` but looking for a more better approach

Answer (score 6):

it's just javascript. Yes you can create div. You have to register on some dom element only once to load up all app. You should avoid touching DOM after load of React app, because React does it in very efficient way, but it doesn't mean that it's not possible to touch it. And before loading React app, if you have to check if app container is there, you may do it with such code:

```
if (!document.getElementById("app")) {    
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = 'app';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer..That's great! but that wasn't I'm looking for (may be I didn't phrase the question properly) Please see the edited question

Comment: That's truly strange that you create dom with React and then creating another part of it from ground up with react again and mounting one react app on another app instead of just building as components of same app. No matter why you have such crazy situation, my answer stays same. It's just javascript and you can use same example, that i've provided, can't see why you couldn't

Comment: actually it's a whole app..its just UI components...I called a function `ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(someFunction,{data:someData}),document.getElementById('someID')` this generated some html with `div id='someDiv1'` and after calling my `someFunction `the very next line I'm calling `React.createElement(someOtherFunction,....,document.getElelmentById(someDiv1)` this says the `somediv1` is not found

Comment: If I try your method I can apped it onto `body` or similar but not on the virtual div created by react

Comment: Why do you need to append on react's dive, just do it *inside* react. The div might not exists at that moment, because react is just loading. To test this theory just wrap around 2nd call with `setTimeout(function(){ /* your 2nd app mount code*/ }, 1000);`